# regular expression of this url

Tags: regex, url

I need regular expression of url such as below

```
http://www.aparat.com/v/bqn5H
http://www.aparat.com/v/raozG
http://www.aparat.com/v/wKZOY
http://www.aparat.com/v/noopj
```

I wrote one but I think it doesn't work

```
http:\/\/www\.aparat\.com\/v\/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)
```

Comment: It's matching all of those for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is correct. I think you are forgetting the `g modifier`.

See here: http://regex101.com/r/tJ1wR5

Also see: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with using the `word` (\w) with one or more quantifier

```
http:\/\/www\.aparat\.com\/v\/\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked my code and I found that this is not exactly what I need.
this is the best fit regular expression:

```
http:\/\/www\.aparat\.com\/v\/.*([a-z0-9-_]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code supports

1. http and https
2. www and without www

code:

```
^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:aparat(-nocookie)?\.com))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/y5atof/1